# Jasper reports table

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a table with jasper, the table is created fine but I only want to jasper shows the table from:

```
Group1 
id Date
1   date1
2   date2
3   date3
Group1 
id Date
1   date1
2   date2
3   date3
```

to:

```
Group1                  Group2
    id Date          id    Date
    1   date1        1   date1
    2   date2        2   date2
    3   date3        3   date3
```

I checked the value group's porperty "start new column" but this not work fine and the result is like the first example

Thanks

Comment: You want the result in a single page?

Comment: This is normally a crosstab problem... check out crosstab's if you have still problem let me know.

Comment: Thanks por your replies, I solved the problem: Firstly I had the "Ignore pagination" but this have not is checked, and the report must to have a number of columns defined.

Comment: I think this is normally crosstab issue. Please check that.